# Python Matplotlib plot multiple data in single graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to find a meaningful way to plot all the data in a single graph.

my data kind of look like this after all transformations -

| Stock | Date | Action | Quantity | Traded % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arihant Tournesol Ltd. | 2022-12-27 | Disposal | 2836900.0 | 28.660477 |
| Asit C Mehta Financial Services Ltd. | 2022-12-28 | Disposal | 380000.0 | 7.839254 |
| HCKK Ventures Ltd. | 2022-12-28 | Acquisition | 1866917.0 | 50.321213 |
| HCKK Ventures Ltd. | 2022-12-28 | Disposal | 1866917.0 | 50.321213 |
| Mafatlal Industries Ltd. | 2022-12-27 | Acquisition | 11500000.0 | 16.316917 |
| Mafatlal Industries Ltd. | 2022-12-27 | Disposal | 11500000.0 | 16.316917 |
| Milgrey Finance & Investments Ltd. | 2022-12-28 | Revoke | 126000.0 | 6.331658 |
| Shreeshay Engineers Ltd. | 2022-12-26 | Disposal | 2460000.0 | 18.631565 |
| Suumaya Corporation Ltd. | 2022-12-27 | Pledge | 10108008.0 | 40.885038 |
| Yarn Syndicate Ltd. | 2022-12-28 | Disposal | 330000.0 | 8.800000 |

```
normal plotting will be like 
df.plot(kind='bar', x='Stock', y='Quantity', color='olivedrab')
```

but this will give a 2-data plot,
I am trying to get all the data plotted on single graph

another way it can be done -

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='Stock', y='Quantity', figsize=(16, 8), color='olivedrab')

ax1 = df['Traded %'].plot(secondary_y=True, ax=ax, color='indianred')

ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

this generates a pic like this, please check the link - but i am missing the date.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VNYC.jpg

Please, if you have any other way to plot them in a single graph, please share...

Comment: it seems your table header is shifted and there are no % values

Comment: A sketch of what you want the final chart to look like would help. for example, how do you want to map the categorical Quantity column to y-axis values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ax1 = sns.set_style(style=None, rc=None )

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

sns.lineplot(data = df,x='Stock', y='Traded', marker='o', sort = False, ax=ax1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

sns.barplot(data = df, x='Stock', y='Quantity', alpha=0.5, ax=ax2)
```